# ¿Por qué el menú de navegación modifica su tamaño cuando le pongo position:fixed?

Tags: html, css

Tengo el siguiente problema: cree un menú de navegación, este tiene un ancho de 100%-1000px, la cosa es que cuando quiero poner que este menú se quede estático(position:fixed)el ancho del menú aumenta y obtiene más de 1000px, cuando le quieto el position:fixed vuelve a su estado normal, ¿por qué sucede esto?

```css
/*MENÚ DE NAVEGACIÓN*/
.cabecera{
 width: 100%;
 background:aqua;
 margin-bottom: 1%;
 position: fixed;
 top: -15px;
}
.cabecera h1{
 display: inline;
 margin-right: 25%;
 margin-left: 12%;
 color: rgba(18,54,78,1);
 padding-bottom: 1%;
}
.lista{
 padding-top: 0;
}
.lista li{
 display: inline;
 list-style: none;
}
.lista li a{
 text-decoration: none;
}
.lista li:hover{
 background: blue;
}
```

```html
<nav class="cabecera">
  <ul class="lista">
   <h1>CAMILO</h1>
   <li><a href="index.html#seccion_baner">Inicio|</a></li>
   <li><a href="index.html#seccion_sobremi">Acerca de mí|</a></li>
   <li><a href="index.html#seccion_servicios">Servicios|</a></li>
   <li><a href="index.html#seccion_portafolio">Portafolio|</a></li>
   <li><a href="index.html#seccion_contacto">Contacto</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: El nombre Camilo debe aparecer a lado de los items del menú?

Comment: He editado el snippet porque tenias el código puesto en los bloques equivocados y no se visualizaba el ejemplo. Lo que comentas en tu pregunta no se corresponde con el código que has puesto en el código, tienes un ancho de 50% y se muestra igual con el `fixed` o sin él.

Comment: Sip, porque estaba probando cambiándole el ancho, pero de igual forma si lo cambio al ampliar la página o al volverla pequeña se modifica . El nombre debe ir al lado de la lista.

Comment: Ya modifiqué el código.

Comment: No entiendo a qué te refieres, no veo nada raro al redimensionar la ventana

Comment: No entiendo realmente cual es tu problema. Tienes `position:fixed` y `width: 100%` por lo que el encabezado te va a ocupar todo el espacio. No veo por ninguna parte el -1000px que comentas en el enunciado.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar del modo siguiente **(No se si sea la mejor opción claro esta)**:

- Al contenedor le aplicas la propiedad de `position: fixed;`, eso hará que su ancho se modifique
- Aplicas un ancho mínimo de **`100%`** al contenedor de los elementos del menú para hacer que de nuevo se extienda a lo máximo de la ventana
- Preferí modificar en algo el código indicando que su `display: flex;`
- Hago uso de `align-items` para alinear verticalmente los elementos dado que tendrán una disparidad con respecto del h1

Código propuesto

```
<style>
  .cabecera__menu {
    display: flex;
    background-color: red;
    position: fixed;
    min-width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .cabecera__elemento {
    list-style: none;
    padding-right: 10px;
  }
  .cabecera__titulo {
    padding-right: 20px;
    margin: 0px;
  }
  a {
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 530px) {
    .cabecera__menu {
      flex-direction: column;
    }
  }
</style>

<nav class="cabecera">
        <ul class="cabecera__menu">
            <h1 class="cabecera__titulo">CAMILO</h1>
            <li class="cabecera__elemento"><a href="">Inicio|</a></li>
            <li class="cabecera__elemento"><a href="">Acerca de mí|</a></li>
            <li class="cabecera__elemento"><a href="">Servicios|</a></li>
            <li class="cabecera__elemento"><a href="">Portafolio|</a></li>
            <li class="cabecera__elemento"><a href="">Contacto</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

`position:fixed` hace que los tamaños de tu elemento vayan en relación a toda tu pantalla, si tienes que de ancho mide 100%, el elemento abarcará toda la pantalla. Podrías intentar poner un ancho de 10% para lo que necesitas.

Comment: La cosa es que modifico el tamaño para un tamaño fijo, osea modifico el ancho para que se ajuste a lo que necesito pero cuando utilizo el zoom este tamaño se modifica y queda feo

Comment: En ese caso, deberías usar `position: absolute`, para que tu barra de navegación se quede con el tamaño que tu quieres.

Comment: Pero no se quedaría estática al bajar el mause.

Comment: Lo único que me imagino sería adaptar a través de media para cada pantalla. ¿Qué piensas?

Comment: Tu menú lateral será absolute, y para todo lo que este de lado, podrías hacer de ese espacio un div con la propiedad `overflow-y: scrollbar`, y ahi metes todo lo que gustes y solo a ese espacio se le hará scroll

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo porque querrías hacer un "menu/cabecera" del 100% - 1000px, pero en cualquier caso este supuesto no figura en tu css si quiersieras de verdad hacer algo así una manea de hacerlo es mediante un cálculo del width:

```
 .cabecera {
    width: calc(100% - 1000px);
  }
```

Un mejor manera de darle un ancho bien proporcionado sería darle un porcentaje del total de la pantalla teniendo en cuenta las necesidades de las @media para todos los dispositivos, o en su defecto una ancho cerrado en píxeles, aunque esto útlimo no te lo recomiendo por su alta probabilidad de romper.

Answer (score 0):

Pensemos que tu pantalla tiene **1000px** de ancho.

En un elemento normal, un ancho de 100% sería el 100% disponible de su elemento padre (en este caso el `<body>`). Ese 100% disponible es 1000px menos los márgenes, que si no están explícitos en la hoja de estilos los define el navegador y es por defecto de 8px en Chromium y Firefox. En otras palabras, estamos hablando de **984px**.

Un elemento con posición `fixed` pasa por alto ciertos atributos que en otro caso heredaría de sus nodos padres. En tu caso, pasa por alto el ancho disponible del body y ocupa los 1000px de la ventana.

Peeero, como no le dijiste explícitamente que se ubicara en `left:0`, sí se ubica acorde a la posición que le sugiere el body. A 8px del borde izquierdo. En comparación con el layout original, se te escapa por el borde derecho en 16px.

Solución:

```
.cabecera{
    background:aqua;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
    position: fixed;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top: -15px;
}
```

Si le dices `left:0` y `right:0` necesariamente es el 100% del ancho. También podrías decirle `left:0` y `width:100%`, pero cuando se trabaja con elementos fijos las dimensiones porcentuales pueden ser engañosas.